# ignore text between <code> tag with preg_replace

Tags: php

I am creating a function to convert markdown to html,
for example

code :

```
   $text = preg_replace(
        "/\*\*(.+?)\*\*/s",
        "<b>$1</b>",
        $text
    );
```

**hello** -> **hello**

but i want to ignore the text between <code> tag

for exemple

input

```
**hello**
<code class="language-c">
**hello**
</code>
```

output

**hello**

<code class="language-c">
**hello**
</code>

Comment: Good luck doing that with RegEx, they aren't suited to parse nested expressions. Write a proper parser instead, there will **always** be example where RegExes won't work

Comment: @Cid isn't it possible to do it by checking if there are not <code> tag before and after ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I did it with `preg_replace_callback` simply by adding a backslash before every chars between `<code>` tag, and ignoring chars preceded by antislash:

```php
    $text = preg_replace_callback(
        "/\<code(.*)\>(.+?)\<\/code\>/s",
        function ($matches) {
            $result = "";
            $match = html_entity_decode($matches[0]);
            $match = str_split($matches[0]);
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($match); $i++) {
                $char = $match[$i];
                $result = $result . "\\$char";
            }
            return $result;
        },
        $text
    );

   $text = preg_replace(
        "/(?<!\\\\)\*\*(.+?)\*\*/s",
        "<b>$1</b>",
        $text
    );
```